# Entity framework init.ps1 file creating problems cant run commands

Tags: c#, entity-framework, powershell-core

Having a lot of problems with this error in the package manager console.
Sometimes it does not show up on start and everything works. But when I restart my computer sometimes it comes up when running visual studio and then I cant seem to get past it.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IGXWr.png)

& : The term 'C:\Users-----.nuget\packages\microsoft.entityframeworkcore.tools\6.0.1\tools\init.ps1' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:45

- ... rgs+=$_}; & 'C:\Users----.nuget\packages\microsoft.entityframe ...
- ```
              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  ```

  - CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\Users\gsprit...\tools\init.ps1:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Tried restarting VS, restarting machine,  uninstalling and installing EF packages. All of this multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

For me it started working when I launched Visual Studio as an administrator. I think the problem has to do with Powershell security policies.